# How to improve multiple eloquent conditions?

Tags: laravel

Here is a default eloquent condition:

```
if($request->has("parent")) =>  {

Specializatio::where('id', $request->id)
    ->when($request->parentid, function($query) use ($request){
        return $query->where('parent_id', $request->parent_id);
    })

}
```

It grows up so fast into long list of conditions `.when` based request object. Is there any flexibale mechanism to manage it, maybe devide in another class, helper?

Comment: Check this video will helps a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XqEJO-wt7s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes) and short hand functions will make your code a bit cleaner.

```php
class Specialization extends Model
{
    public function scopeParent($query, $parentId)
    {
        return $query->where('parent_id', $parentId);
    }
}

Specialization::whereKey($request->id)
    ->when($request->filled('parent_id'), fn ($query) => $query->parent($request->parent_id));
```